# How to Handle Multiple date field component in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation

I have multiple date component how to automate all the date using selenium java.
can anybody help me ?

i will explain scenario here

- i have multiple date in one page (Open date, Close Date ,Preview Date,Checkout Start Date,Checkout End Date)
  **lets say for example**

Open Date  : 06/15/2023
Close Date : 06/25/2023
Preview Date : 06/20/2023
Checkout Start Date : 06/17/2023
Checkout End Date : 06/24/2023

would anybody help me how to automate all the date

would anybody help me how to automate all the date